# Hyphen class is not working in javascript

Tags: javascript

In my script i used hyphen class but it's show error means not working. please help me how to used hyphen class in JavaScript. Please check my code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my-firstli").my-firstli({
      items: 1,
      itemsDesktop: [1000, 2],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 2],
      itemsTablet: [768, 2],
      itemsMobile: [650, 1],
      pagination: true,
      navigation: false,
      slideSpeed: 1000,
      autoPlay: true
    });
  }); 
</script>
```

So in this you check class (my-firstli) not working. Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: What plugin you're using?

Comment: `$(".my-firstli").my-firstli({` is invalid syntax. What were you hoping to do there?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to use the OwlCarousel jQuery plugin. Make sure to import it first in your project. Anyways, here's the valid syntax for your example:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".my-firstli").owlCarousel({
      items: 1,
      itemsDesktop: [1000, 2],
      itemsDesktopSmall: [979, 2],
      itemsTablet: [768, 2],
      itemsMobile: [650, 1],
      pagination: true,
      navigation: false,
      slideSpeed: 1000,
      autoPlay: true
    });
  }); 
</script>
```